# yii2: Dynamically call widget

Tags: javascript, ajax, widget, yii2

Lets imagine that I have some widget: Widget1;

I call this widget in view file.

```
<?= Widget1::widget() ?>
```

When you click on some element, a new instance of the widget should be called and  execute js scripts of this widget. 
I can not realize the script execution after ajax call;

Answer (score 0):

Create an ajax call to a controller action where you will instantiate your widget and/or call it's javascript returning functions. Like this:

```
//@app/widget/Widget1
class Widget1 extends \yii\base\Widget
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo new JsExpression('function(){ alert("hello,world") }');
    }
}

//@app/controllers/SomeController
public function actionSomeaction()
{
    return Widget1::widget();
}
```

And then call that from your ajax function that's handling onClick event(example in jquery):

```
<script>
    $.post('/some/someaction',function(response){
        response();
    });
</script>
```